# How to give unit price for product in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10

For Example,
  Quantity of Product = 100 (here we can specify any unit of measure)
    Unit Price        =  55 RS

Total amount will be 55 RS Only.Neither to be calculate the amount for per quantity.

How to configuration price like that or any module is available for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The total price will be a computed field if I understand your question :

```
qte = fields.Integer(string="Qte") 
#or qte = fields.Integer(related='yourmodule.qte', store=True, string="Qte", readonly=True)
unit_price = fields.Integer(string="Unit price")
#or unit_price = fields.Integer(related='yourmodule.unit_price', store=True, string="Unit price", readonly=True)
total_price = fields.Integer(string="Total Price", compute="_compute_qte_total", readonly=True)

@api.depends('qte', 'unit_price')
    def _compute_qte_total(self):
        for rec in self:
            if((isinstance(rec.qte, int))and(isinstance(rec.unit_price, int))):
                rec.qte_total = rec.qte * rec.unit_price
```

I think you should try to solve the problem in this way. Just handle it with your fields and class.